# Does passing data in props duplicate that data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a dashboard in React, and currently I'm looking at building a small button component that will allow a user to download data from a chart as a CSV file. Something like this:

```
// Dashboard
render(){
  const data=makeLargeDataset(); // make an array with 1m rows
  return (
    <DownloadCSV data={data} />
  );
}

// Download Button
onClick(){
  if (this.props.data){
    convertAndDownload(this.props.data);
  }
}
```

Does this duplicate the 1M rows when passing to the button's prop? If I had to pass a prop through several layers, will it keep duplicating? Is there a smarter way to pass props -- or work with large variables and arrays, in general -- so it isn't as wasteful or inefficient?

Comment: Duplicate? You're passing a reference.

Comment: Easy way to check would be to try to change the data in one of the lower layers and see if it is not reflected at the top layer.  If it is not reflected, then the elements are not the same.  I would expect them to be the same though.

Comment: Passing data via props does not duplicate the data... it more like passing you are passing a copy of the data to another component...

Comment: @DAMMAK "Does not duplicate..." and "passing a copy..." seem diametrically opposed. You're passing a reference to the data.

Comment: okay... that's actually right!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, It does not.

Any props passed from a higher order component to a child component always references the same props. It's called *Single Source of Truth*. You can alter one data point in the HO Component and React as the name tells reacts to only the change and nothing else.

A simple way for holding such big data sets would be to use a store like `Redux` to keep the data safe but the smarter way would be to create an API or a micro service based on your needs and call that rather than loading a million rows on the browser.

Comment: Does your reponse change if I'm not talking about higher-order components? And you're right about the service. I don't actually store a million rows, it's just an extreme to get the point across. But I am concerned keeping memory usage down, etc.

Comment: Nope, I would still prefer using a separate API which does that so that when i need to change a style or insert something i would do so at that endpoint and not alter my front end.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the data copy, you are passing the reference.

You could think about paginating your data in some way in order to handle lower sized arrays.